# Only change one viewport in Aurelia router

Tags: aurelia

Good morning, I have my route setup as shown below within Aurelia CLI.

```
config.map([
    { 
        route: [''],
        viewPorts: {
           'side': { moduleId: 'side' },
           'main': { moduleId: 'main' }
        },
        title: 'Test',
        nav: false,
        name: 'Temp'
]);
```

What I would like to do is based on what I select on my side view, I just want to change the moduleId for main and load that view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to dynamically change the moduleId of a view-port. I see 2 options to solve your proble:

1 - Create another route, changing the moduleId of one of the viewports

2 - Use the layout mechanism and change its content in run time. I recommend you to read http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/10.

I know this is not the answer you were expecting but I hope it helps.